# Weird repost of last picture in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Sorry Balpha!

In SuperUser chat, the moment I click the upload button, it reposts the last picture I uploaded.

I am able to reproduce every single time.

I am guessing that refreshing/closing and reopening will clear the issue, so, I won't do that just yet in case I can be any help in finding out what is happening.

[Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0EbvStFBN8)

... I am around in Super User chat if there is anything I can do.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? This has come up for a few of us before, but I know when it happened to me balpha blamed my dev browser, heheh. Refreshing the tab will indeed fix the problem.

Comment: So, am I to understand [your Westie loves pringles?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QgbF4tpAJ8&feature=related)  And why so much Jonas Brothers and Bieber Feverers in the *Suggested Videos*?

Comment: @Won't - can't comment about Jonas Brothers :/ The suggested thing is weird - my brothers videos (he does magic performances... http://edwardhilsum.com ) used to keep linking to strange sex videos! I think if you don't do meta data or anything, it just does random videos as the moment he typed about his act, they went ... But... my westie does love pringles! ... That was when he was just a few months old!

Comment: @Tim Stone - 11.0.696.71

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue and started [some speculating](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/649849#649849) on what the root cause was, but I'm still really unsure. It does appear to be Chrome's fault, though.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out *why* it's doing what it's doing, but I think there might be a hack to work around it anyway. Let me know if it happens to you again, since there's something I want to independently verify if you don't mind testing.

Comment: @Tim I've been having this for several versions of Chrome now, just never bothered to report because I'm on the Dev Channel

Comment: @Ivo I could only reproduce this starting today

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a very ugly Chrome bug that causes the IFRAME that is the target for the image upload to immediately re-POST the previous request when it's added to the DOM.

I couldn't reliably reproduce it, until I found [this very probably related Chrome bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=59576) (it might also be related to [these two](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24078) [WebKit bug reports](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28657), but I'm not certain about that).

Indeed, uploading an image -> going to a different room -> clicking "back" -> clicking "upload" immediately re-uploaded the old image.

Many thanks go to [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235/tim-stone), who has spent quite some time debugging this issue and found a workaround: If name/id of the IFRAME are different each time, Chrome will *not* do the re-upload. So from now on, the IFRAME's name and id are unique every time (by including a timestamp as well as a random number).

Comment: I assume the fix isn't live yet, since I just had this problem again

Comment: @IvoFlipse: It is live -- but you need the fresh JavaScript, so if you haven't reloaded the page since the deploy (which happend shortly before I posted this answer), you're still having the old behavior. I assume that's the case?

Comment: Yes, I actually refreshed the page after it happened, because that somehow seemed to remedy the problem. So its probably gone now :-)

Comment: Well done to both you and @Tim Stone! .... especially as it wasn't your problem! :) Thought you had forgotten about this.

Comment: ... will unmark if it comes back as @Ivo said.