# Avira AntiVir triggering on all stack-exchange sites

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virus reported after loading page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111351/virus-reported-after-loading-page)

A few days ago, Avira AntiVir started triggering everytime I view a posting on a stack-exchange site. The reported threat is the following: http://www.avira.com/en/support-threats-summary-product/tid/3682/threat/HTML%252FRce.Gen/track/1

I can provide more details if needed.