# SO broken due to JavaScript from another domain being blocked or failing to load

Tags: support, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [External JavaScript code failed to load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96373/external-javascript-code-failed-to-load)

I've got a nice red bar at the top for SO and Meta, telling me:

> Meta Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.

This results not only in convenience features being gone (preview, tag-completion etc.), but even prevents me from posting comments.

*As i can't comment:*

- I am not blocking JS. Also, this fails for Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer.
- The error console shows 403 for [a script](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js). Turns out this one blocked by Avira for being Malware... WTF?

Comment: Are you blocking external JavaScript, or should it be working?

Comment: Strange. Can you check in Chrome's developer console (F12) in the "Network" tab whether all JS gets loaded?

Comment: Hm, could be related to [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111351/150235) since jQuery uses `Math.random()`.

Comment: Alright, false-positive-report sent, exception added... SO is usable again, thanks @Pekka.

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate, had the same problem, Avira blocked jQuery (false positive, hopefully) - added exception too and everythings working again. Close voters were too fast this time.