# "Eicar-Test-Signature" virus alert when accessing Question link on SE sites?

Tags: support

I'm not sure if this is the result of a SE change, or changes to my anti-virus, however I am suddenly getting this image whenever I click the "Questions" link on any SE site

[image]

It just started a few hours ago. Did you do anything on your end that would cause my anti-virus program to think the questions page contains a virus?

It should be noted that I can access the questions page just fine by adding a / to the end of the URL

- stackoverflow.com/questions - Doesn't work
- stackoverflow.com/questions/ - Works

Comment: Maybe somebody asked a question containing the [EICAR test file](http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html)?

Comment: @minitechη It is happening on all SE sites, not just Stack Overflow.

Comment: Possibility: an ad or something might have had it once, and your antivirus blocked it permanently for that particular URL. It would explain why adding `/` works... but I suppose it's unlikely.

Comment: @minitechη It seems unlikely that the same ad is the first add that appears on all the SE sites. I get this error on SO, P.SE, DBA.SE, UX.SE, SO Meta, P.SE Meta, and I just tried Cooking.SE since I know that's a site I almost never login to and it gives me the same message

Comment: Are we supposed to discuss a bug? `:)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno Sure, I'm not positive it's actually an SE bug or a change to my anti-virus software or firewall. I'm hoping an SE employee can tell me if they changed anything this morning which could possibly cause this.

Comment: Should not tagging the question [meta-tag:support], and eventually replacing the tag with [meta-tag:bug] (if it comes out to be a bug) be better?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I wasn't really sure which tag to use, so just entered it as a bug. Feel free to change the tags if you want :)

Comment: *Sigh...* I guess [this time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111361/115866) someone used numbers and strings in the JavaScript? That's always suspicious.

Comment: @balpha despite your warnings, I like to sprinkle `eval` here and there.  Keeps you on your toes.

Comment: @balpha It appears to be fixed today... did you do something? :)

Comment: Nope, didn't do anything. And we certainly don't and didn't host the eicar test file anywhere :)

Comment: @balpha I spoke too soon anyways, the issue's back again. Perhaps it's just my anti-virus or firewall acting up...