# Avira virus/malware warning when opening/asking a question

Tags: support, virus

Similar as in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100817/avast-reporting-virus-when-browsing-to-so-question Avira starts to complain about a virus warning every time I open a question in the tex.stackexchange but also when I tried to ask this question here on meta.
I can't see the tool bar at the top now where it allows me to insert hyperlinks, figures etc. thus here the link to the report

[image: virus warning (German)]
[image: virus warning (English)]

Comment: I'm getting this, too.

Comment: I reported the (probable) false-positive to Avira. Let's see what happens...

Comment: This question is related to [Virus reported after loading page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111351/virus-reported-after-loading-page). Seems that the false positive went back into their virus definition file.

Comment: getting it too, on so and meta

Comment: I'm getting it too - I've added a copy of the warning in English.  If you have the appropriate privileges on your machine, one workaround tho this is to disable just the "web protection" element of Avira, without disabling the main realtime antivirus protection.

Comment: @matthias: I wonder what black hat hacking tool we are using now.

Comment: It looks like they're at it again, last time it was a using `Math.Random` more than once in the file...definitely a bug on their end as a result of this update: http://forum.avira.com/wbb/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=144309

Answer (score 2):

After reporting this false-positive to [Avira](http://www.avira.com), there was an update to the virus definition file. With version `7.11.29.70` there should be no alerts anymore.

If not, you could add <s>`http://stackoverflow.com`</s> `cdn.sstatic.net` to your URL exclusion list (see image below). I got only the german version running on my PC but you should find the setting *at the same position* (EDIT: mind the changed URL).

[image: Avira: exclude URL]

Comment: Since it happens to me at work and I have no access to the Avira options I'm bound to wait until Avira changes this.