# Missing toolbar and not getting any preview of posted answer

Tags: bug

I am not getting any preview information of what I write in a question box (like right now) nor when I try to post an answer.  Also, there is no toolbar and no code window resize slider bar either.

It's happening on Chrome, FireFox, and Internet Explorer, and on different machines here at work.

Per Dennis' suggestion, I played around with the Console, and I found this:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (OK)
>   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/wmd.js?v=dcfaf6cb7e9c

When I try to go to that link, our Astaro router reports:

> **Content Blocked**
>   The item you have requested is infected by a virus. It will not be downloaded.

I'm assuming that's not really the case, but I'm not sure what to do about this now.

Comment: I'm also on the latest version of Chrome (18.0.1025.168), and everything works as it should. Try a hard refresh (`[Ctrl] + [F5]`).

Comment: First things first: Are you a human?

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast: I thought posting on Meta **was** the human verification.

Comment: @LarsTech: Sounds like a problem with the CDN. What does the console say?

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast What's the test for that?  I'm not very good at tests.

Comment: Same here and I also don't see the toolbar.

Comment: @Dennis I think this is what you want me to check: I have a Tools - Developer Tools "console" opened on an edit page.  How do I determine a problem with the CDN?

Comment: @LarsTech: Hard refresh the page with the console open and see if any error pops up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virus/malware warning when opening/asking a question \[Avira\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131172/virus-malware-warning-when-opening-asking-a-question-avira)

Comment: @Arjan Actually, that post actually links to a more closer duplicate: [Virus reported after loading page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111351/162993)

Comment: True, @Lars, but that one is 6 months old...